# Prevent image slideshow grows more than container cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a little html-jquery program that generate dynamically a table where on each cell there are an [slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp). The slideshow get the images that you select from a folder inside your computer.

The problem is that when I select the folder **the slideshow gets the height to 100vh for each cell with slideshow**. I can't understand how prevent that the slideshow grows more than the containing cell.

**HTML**

```html
<body style="height:100vh;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        Rows: <input id="sRows" type="number" name="" value="2">
        Columns: <input id="sCol" type="number" name="" value="2">
        <button id="btnGen" type="button" name="button">Generate!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div  id="slideshowContiner" class="w3-table-all" >
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
  #slideshowContiner {
        table-layout: fixed;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .slider{
        max-width:100%;
        max-height: 100%;
      }
      .mySlide{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
      }
```

For Javascript code maybe is too long for read, finally the created structure is, inside the `#slideshowContiner` is something like that:

```html
<div id="slideshowContiner" class="w3-table-all">
  <tr></tr>
  <td style="background-color:#6a833c">
    <input webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="" msdirectory="" odirectory="" directory="" multiple="" type="file" name="file">
    <div class="w3-content w3-section slider" style="">
      <img class="mySlide" style="display: none;" src="blob:null/">
      <img class="mySlide" style="display: none;" src="blob:null/">
      <img class="mySlide" style="display: none;" src="blob:null/">
    </div>
    </td>
  </div>
```

**Jquery (TL:DR;)**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
      var randomColor = function (){
          return '#'+ ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6);
      }

      var sliders = []
      var myIndex = 0;

      function carousel() {
        var i;
        var slides = elem.children( ".mySlide" ).css("display", "none")
        console.log(slides, this);
      }
      function createSlider(files){
        var slider = $('<div class="w3-content w3-section slider" style=""></div>')
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          prev = $('<img class="mySlide" style="">').attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(files[i]))
          slider.append(prev)
        }
        sliders.push(slider)
        // slider.data("id", inn++)
        var myIndex = 0;
        slider.data("slideshow", function(){
          console.log(myIndex);
          var slides = slider.children( ".mySlide" ).css("display", "none")
          myIndex++;
          if (myIndex > slides.length) {myIndex = 1}
          console.log(slides[myIndex]);
          $(slides[myIndex-1]).css("display", "block")
          setTimeout(slider.data("slideshow"), 2000)

        })
        return slider
      }

      var sContainer = $("#slideshowContiner")
      var sRows = $("#sRows")
      var sCol = $("#sCol")
      var btnGen = $("#btnGen")

      function genGrid(){
        sContainer.html("")
        for (var i = 0; i < sRows.val(); i++) {
          var newRow = sContainer.append('<tr></tr>')
          // var newRow = sContainer.append('<div class="row flex-fill d-flex " style="border: 1px solid;"></div>')
          for (var x = 0; x < sCol.val(); x++) {
            var newCol = $('<td style="background-color:'+randomColor()+'"></td>')
            newRow.append(newCol);
            var input = $('<input webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple/>')
                .attr('type', "file")
                .attr('name', "file")
                .on("change", function() {
                  cell = $(this).data("cell")
                  var s = createSlider(this.files)
                  cell.append(s)
                  // carousel(s)
                  var init = s.data("slideshow")();

                })
                .data("cell", newCol);;
            newCol.append($(input))
          }
        }
      }
      genGrid()
      btnGen.click(genGrid)
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwL2rk0d/1/).

**Note:** on this fiddle the `style="height:100vh;"` are on the root div, on the original code are on the body tag.

Comment: add jsfiddle or snippet I do not understand you problem :D

Comment: I add the fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

You could set each image to a fixed height using a static unit such as `px` in your class, and use a few media queries to control their dimensions in different resolutions.  This way you can expect what they will look like.

Comment: I never do that before, could you provide some example/tutorial?

Comment: `.mySlide{  width:100%; height: 128px; }` instead of `auto`, I put `128px`. Try changing that out in your code.

Comment: But, as if you see on jsfiddle, the cell is automatically generated, depending how much rows cells the user selects. How can I set the height based on this and on the user screen?